# implicitly convert between two 'identical' types in swift

Tags: swift, types, casting

If I have two types

```
struct PersonFromLibraryA {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}

struct PersonFromLibraryB {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}
```

Is there a way to implicitly be able to pass an `A` into a method which is expecting a `B`?

```
func doSomething(withPerson person: PersonFromLibraryA) { 
    ...
}

let person = PersonFromLibraryB(name: "Alice", age: 42)

doSomething(withPerson: person))
```

I'd expect this to be type safe i.e. if A or B diverge *in any way whatsoever*, this shouldn't compile.

I have about 20 or so of this situation (I'm mapping between layers of abstraction in a library) and am getting very tired of filling files with boilerplate mapping methods!

I suspect I already know the answer to this question, but I figure I'll ask it here just to be sure!

Comment: Why not **one** struct with a `fromLibrary` property (an enum) or a protocol which both structs conform to and which is used as the type in the method parameter.

Comment: Agreed with rmaddy that the one way to fix this w/ type-saftey is protocol (without type-safety, you can do it with unsafeBitCast, but please don't do that). This raises a warning flag, though, that you may have over-abstracted something (or more likely: abstracted along the wrong axis) if you have many types that are identical but distinct between layers.

Comment: Yea, the more I'm writing this the more I think I've over engineered my layers - I'm trying to avoid my public classes(structs) implementing a protocol which is only used internally. So I've implemented the protocol on an internal set of classes so it's not exposed. I'm beginning to think that I should just accept that it's going to be public, and halve my codebase!

Comment: Hey @RobNapier - can you add 'you may have over-abstracted something (or more likely: abstracted along the wrong axis) if you have many types that are identical but distinct between layers' from your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed with rmaddy that the one way to fix this w/ type-saftey is protocol (without type-safety, you can do it with unsafeBitCast, but please don't do that). This raises a warning flag, though, that you may have over-abstracted something (or more likely: abstracted along the wrong axis) if you have many types that are identical but distinct between layers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should think OOP as Swift is an OOP language. Change both into classes. Generally, you can do this by simply changing the word struct to class. Then create a new class.

```
class PersonFromLibrary {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}
```

Now setup your other classes:

```
class PersonFromLibraryA: PersonFromLibrary {
}

class PersonFromLibraryB: PersonFromLibrary {
}
```

Now instead of using `PersonFromLibraryA` as the parameter type use `PersonFromLibrary`. Now you can pass all of the `PersonFromLibraryA` type things as `PersonFromLibrary`. The only restriction here is that if you add any unique qualities to any of the `PersonFromLibraryA` level classes you will have to cast it back to `PersonFromLibraryA` or it's corresponding class in order to use its unique properties.